# Filter library by current user using url

Tags: list-view, filter, url

so I know in the view editor one can add the option of filtering by [me]. My question, is is there any way to do this in the URL and not the view?

I would like to keep the standard allitems.aspx, but add a filter like such:
?&FilterField1=Editor&FilterValue1=[Me]

Now, I tested this and it doesn't work, it filters by the literal value of "[me]", which we have no users with that name (obviously).

Comment: I think no. Why are you trying to do that? Perhaps there is another approach

Comment: I am trying to work on parameter based pages where we load in different document libraries, each with the same filter, based on the URL parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JSOM you can find the current user login and create the View URL dynamically.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
var currentUser = oWeb.get_currentUser();
clientContext.load(currentUser);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    //currentUser.get_loginName();
    //currentUser.get_id();
}, function(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
});
```

Comment: is the .get_loginName() function what returns the name i should filter by?